# How can I successfully send http requests to my ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin

I have built a .NET Core server that is linked up to a postgres database but what I'm attempting to do now is send requests to the server from a mobile app to execute the CRUD functions with the server. This is so the mobile can send requests that will be an object using a model that's setup in both server and mobile app to be the same. Then the server will POST that request to the database.

This code is on the mobile app that makes a baseAddress for the server and then the other code is inside a save method that turns the object into json string and presumably sends it to the controller.

```
private static readonly HttpClient sharedClient = new()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.188.144.18:5240/AandEBacklog"),
        };

using StringContent jsonContent = new(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { note }),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

using HttpResponseMessage response = await sharedClient.PostAsync("MobileResponse", jsonContent);
```

I know that I need to do something with routing in the program.cs file in the server

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```

I have a controller that connects to the database but don't know weather I can use the `httpRequest` in that controller or if I need to send it to another one and then the other controller handles it

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace delamainServer.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AandEBacklogController : ControllerBase
{
    //CONNECTING TO DATABASE.
    private readonly DataContext context;

    //var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;

    public AandEBacklogController(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //post method example to add entry
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<AandEBacklog>>> Addemrgncy(AandEBacklog booking)
    {
        context.AandEBacklogs.Add(booking);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(await context.AandEBacklogs.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear on where you're stuck?  Does your service work and you just need to connect from the client?  Or do you still need to get your service working?

Comment: Apologies. My service works, I am trying to get my mobile xamarin app using httpClient to send a request to the server. it's mapping the http request so it reached the post method specifically that I am having difficulty understanding.

Comment: if a request can't reach the correct endpoint then your service is not working correctly

Comment: What is actual problem, error, exception?

Comment: Okay so my service works to the point where I can do all CRUD commands using swagger to manipulate entries in the postgres database. I have also read about making a httpClient request to the server and pretty certain that the code at the top is correct but found it difficult to test without knowing if the server is setup correctly to receive. I think to help it reach the correct endpoint I need to do something with the routing but am unsure

Comment: I am trying to get my mobile phone client application to send requests to the server. currently the requests do not reach the endpoint. I want the mobile app to send a request to the server so the server can then deal with it and put it in the correct place in the database. I am starting small and just trying to post a model object to the server and then get the server to post the object to my table in postgres

Comment: Ive also just noticed that for some reason its deleted my description from the question for some reason

Comment: are you able to do requests through postman?

Comment: is the request even reaching the server?  What http response code do you get?  Or is the request timing out?  The most common issue in these scenarios is that your server is not setup to handle remote requests

Comment: I haven't tried postman but swagger works fine

Comment: Okay So I'm not getting any much response when I try to send requests. not understanding the full process of sending through requests has lead me to just attempting to get an object sent to the server and hopefully spot it reaching there with debugger. to get the function properly working I think I need to deserialise the  httprequest variable back to the object which I guess needs setting to a new instance of the model class on the server. and the method accepts booking as a parameter but I think the request has to be declared in a action so maybe i get rid of that and just insert the httpreq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client part:

```
    var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.188.144.18:5240") };
    var content = new StringContent("yourJsonString", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("/AandEBacklog", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**EDIT:**
Let's setup simple GET endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TimeController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult<string> GetCurrentTime() => $"{DateTime.Now}";
}
```

Verify it works from browser (e.g. http://localhost:5000/Time).
If it works try client from console or Xamarin app:

```
var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000") };
var response = await client.GetAsync("/Time");
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: I've tried it in debug and as far as I am aware Im not really getting any response back through it. I am attempting to send it to a controller thats been pulled from an example in an attempt to receive it and not the controller thats doing the CRUD actions.

Comment: At least some error or exception should be helpful.

Comment: if you're not getting a response its most likely a timeout.  If you are using the built in VS web server then it is not configured to handle remote requests by default.  99% this is the root issue

Comment: Im using a multi platform xamarin app for the ios and android mobile and then I made an asp.net core server project and connected it to the postgres server with CRUD controls. I haven't done anything on the server for accepting requests and I far as ive got so far is that I need to get the routing correct and then it should work.

Comment: "I haven't done anything on the server for accepting requests" - you have said that it works with Swagger.  This is incredibly confusing to the many people trying to help you.  Setup a simple HTTP Get endppoint that just returns the time.  Verify it works from your browser/swagger/postman.  If it does, then try to connect to it from your Xamarin app.

Comment: response {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler+NSUrlSessionDataTaskStreamContent, Headers: {   Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2023 02:12:44 GMT   Server: Kestrel   Content-Length: 0   Allow: DELETE   Al…}

Comment: I managed to add your suggestion and get it to show something in the response in debug

Comment: I have little knowledge on this topic and so Im trying to describe it as best as I can but Im obviously struggling to explain what Im struggling with because I don't fully understand it. I dont know how to make a simple http get endpoint but I do have CRUD functions that work on swagger but have just had no luck on the xamarin app

Comment: I entered the code and where it says "yourjsonstring" I added the serialiser to convert the note object into the string and then put it in the space where the string was.

Comment: var jsonContent = (JsonSerializer.Serialize(new{ note }));
            var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100:5240") };
            var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Comment: Have you looked up what 405 means?

Comment: it says its something to do with an error on the method type but Im doing it through HttpPost so maybe its mistaking in for something else.

Comment: Ive tried upvoting this as I setup your get time and made a request from the browser and then the xamarin app which has both worked so the mobile application has connected to the server. The post then should be connecting but what Im guessing is its something to do with the method.